# В AspNet 5. identity 3 не работает User.Identity.GetUserId();

Tags: asp.net-identity-2, asp.net-core

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;

var id = User.Identity.**GetUserId**();
```

В AspNet 5. identity 3 не работает `User.Identity.GetUserId();`

> Identity не содержит определения для GetUserId и не удалось найти метод расширения принимающий тип  Identity в качестве первого аргумента

Предлагает добавить :

```
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core 2
```

Но он будет конфликтовать с `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity 3`:

При добавлении Core2 появляется другая ошибка :

Ошибка  :

> CS0433    Тип "UserManager" существует как в "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35", так и в "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60".  WebApplicationZ2016.WEB.DNX 4.5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы получаете Id пользователя в контроллере то напишите так:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc;
public class UserController : Controller
{
   public IActionResult Info()
   {
        var userId = User.GetUserId();
        var userName = User.GetUserName();

        return View();
    }
}
```

В представлениях нужно подключить пространство:

```
using System.Security.Claims
```

И написать:

```
<div>
    @User.GetUserId()
    @User.GetUserName()
</div>
```

Через Context в представлениях можно так:

```
<div>
    @Context.User.GetUserId()
    @Context.User.GetUserName()
</div>
```

Через Context в контролере:

```
    using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc;
    public class UserController : Controller
    {
       public IActionResult Info()
       {
            var userId = HttpContext.User.GetUserId();
            var userName = HttpContext.User.GetUserName();

            return View();
        }
    }
```

В своих собственных классах вы не сможете использовать данные функции.

Comment: Хорошо. А если вне контроллера то как? Вне контроллера раньше работало так HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId(); - не содержит определения для curent

Comment: @mk000000000 добавил в ответ

Comment: *"В своих собственных классах вы не сможете использовать данные функции"* - что за бред?

Comment: @PavelMayorov потому что HttpContext и User являются частью класса Controller

Comment: Во-первых, есть такое статическое свойство как `HttpContext.Current`. Во-вторых, объект `User` можно же и передать в метод как параметр.

Comment: @PavelMayorov передать конечно можно, но само значение мы можем получить только в контроллере (с помощью этих свойств)

Comment: Ну и как это помешает мне вызвать функцию?

Comment: @PavelMayorov если указать HttpContext.User.GetUserId() в своем классе то не заработает (необходим еще код). Еще HttpContext.Current больше не существует в ASP.NET Core

Comment: Колямбий, вы написали - "функция". Функция - это `GetUserId()`, а не `HttpContext.User.GetUserId()`

Comment: Кроме того, вопрос был задан про MVC, а не про Core.

Comment: @PavelMayorov выразился некорректно, а в вопросе сказано про  AspNet 5

Comment: Хм, но тогда там тэги неправильные.

Comment: @PavelMayorov внес правку, в теги, но она должна пройти проверку

Comment: Зачем вы добавили метку обратно?..

Comment: @я наверное сохранил после того как вы внесли изменения, оставил метку asp.net-mvc так как по сути вопрос тоже к MVC относиться